# How do I clear the PEL list for a consumer group in Redis

Tags: redis, redis-streams

I would like to know how to clear the PEL list for a given Redis consumer group without individually acknowledging every message.

**Context**
I have a consumer group for my one of my Redis streams. For testing purposes, I need to clear the PEL list of the consumer group without deleting the stream.

Comment: without deleting the stream & consumer group. 
Sorry for not mentioning this before.

Answer (score 3):

From a consumer view, you can use XPENDING to know which are the message-ids list that are not yet acknowledged. Then using XCLAIM you can claim a specific message.

There is also XAUTOCLAIM command, which composes XPENDING and XCLAIM for every message in the group.

Anyway by design the message is in a PEL and it's removed only when it's acknowledged, claimed by another consumer or deleted from the stream.

[XPENDING](https://redis.io/commands/xpending/)

[XCLAIM](https://redis.io/commands/xclaim/)

[XAUTOCLAIM](https://redis.io/commands/xautoclaim/)

Comment: correction: the message_id in a PEL is NOT removed even when the message is deleted from the stream. Check this issue: https://github.com/redis/go-redis/issues/2514

Answer (score 1):

Redis doesn't implement any command to do that functionality. Only way to remove entries from the PEL of a consumer is to ACK each pending message individually.

This [thread](https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/6199) explains why deleted messages from a stream still are part of a PEL.